# Reliable source proving Moran's I between -1 and 1 for symmetric, row-standardised weight matrices?

Tags: references, autocorrelation, spatial

It appears to me that whenever I read in the literature about **Moran's I having limits between -1 and 1 for row-standardised, symmetric weight matrices**, it is typically presented as a "well known fact", but not quoted with a proper source with derivation. I'm looking for such source, since in my field Moran's I isn't often used, therefore I can't assert such facts being "well known".

I did find a derivation [in the answer to another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160459/why-is-morans-i-coming-out-greater-than-1) but this is of no use to me because:

1. I cannot quote a website,
2. I don't want to copy these calculations and take credit for them.

Are there any reliable sources that may be quoted on that statement?

I am aware of de Jong et al. "On Extreme Values of Moran's I and Geary's C" but that doesn't include the statement that I'm looking for.

Comment: *Of course* you can reuse mathematical calculations in your work!  The only requirement is that you understand them, lest you inadvertently convey something incorrect to your readers (and possibly embarrass yourself).  BTW, you *can* quote a Web site.  The math site even has standards for citing it!